# how to to make embed pdf in html display a pdf document in web view in kotlin jetpack compose

Tags: android, html, kotlin, embed

I use  a web view using this code in jetpack compose android kotlin
how to to make embed pdf in html display a pdf document in web view in kotlin jetpack compose

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView






@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
fun WebViewPage(url: String){

    // Adding a WebView inside AndroidView
    // with layout as full screen
    AndroidView(factory = {
        WebView(it).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            webViewClient = WebViewClient()

            // to play video on a web view
            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

            //delete me
            settings.setSupportZoom(true)
            settings.supportZoom()
            settings.displayZoomControls= false
            settings.builtInZoomControls= true

            // to verify that the client requesting your web page is actually your Android app.
            settings.userAgentString = System.getProperty("http.agent") //Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 11; M2012K11I Build/RKQ1.201112.002)

            loadUrl(url)


        }
    }, update = {
        it.loadUrl(url)
    })




}
```

then I save the html file in the assets folder
the I used this code in the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>



<embed src="file:///android_asset/pdfname.pdf"" width=100% height="800px" />

</body>
</html>
```

the problem that it does not display the pdf document

is it possible to display the pdf in html page in this way ?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to provide the renderer and a Mutex (since PdfRenderer can only render on-page-at a time) ):

```
@Composable
private fun PDFPage(
    renderer: PdfRenderer,
    rendererMutex: Mutex,
    index: Int,
    pageFit: PageFit
) {
    BoxWithConstraints(Modifier.padding(HALF_PAGE_PADDING)) {
        val bitmap by produceState<Bitmap?>(null) {
            withContext(<http://Dispatchers.IO|Dispatchers.IO>) {
                rendererMutex.withLock {
                    renderer.openPage(index).use { page ->
                        val size = pageFit.size(constraints, page.width, page.height)
                        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                            size.width, size.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
                        )
                        page.render(
                            bitmap,
                            null,
                            null,
                            PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY
                        )
                        value = bitmap
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        val imageBitmap = bitmap?.asImageBitmap()
        if (imageBitmap == null) Box(
            when (pageFit) {
                PageFit.FILL_HORIZONTAL -> Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                PageFit.FILL_VERTICAL -> Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
                else -> Modifier
            }.aspectRatio(1f)
        )
        else Image(
            imageBitmap,
            "Page ${index + 1}",
            modifier = Modifier
                .thenIf(pageFit == PageFit.CONTAIN) { align(Alignment.Center) }
                .shadow(4.dp)
                .background(Color.White)
        )
    }
}


private enum class PageFit(val size: (constraints: Constraints, pageWidth: Int, pageHeight: Int) -> IntSize) {
    FILL_HORIZONTAL({ constraints, pageWidth, pageHeight ->
        IntSize(
            constraints.maxWidth,
            (constraints.maxWidth.toFloat() / pageWidth * pageHeight).roundToInt()
        )
    }),
    FILL_VERTICAL({ constraints, pageWidth, pageHeight ->
        IntSize(
            (constraints.maxHeight.toFloat() / pageHeight * pageWidth).roundToInt(),
            constraints.maxHeight,
        )
    }),
    CONTAIN({ constraints, pageWidth, pageHeight ->
        if (pageWidth.toFloat() / constraints.maxWidth > pageHeight.toFloat() / constraints.maxHeight) FILL_VERTICAL.size(
            constraints,
            pageWidth,
            pageHeight
        )
        else FILL_HORIZONTAL.size(constraints, pageWidth, pageHeight)
    })
}
```

Note though above will allow you to display simply but with super basic rendering of pdf. The system API is capable of more sophisticated tile based interactive rendering, but it's a lot more complex to implement by following the PDF official specs.

Comment: is it possible to view the pdf using WebViewPage

Comment: You can open any pdf on internet using google drive link. For example, if your pdf url is:

String pdf = "https://mywebsite/mypdf.pdf"

Just embed this link in following google drive link:

String gDrive = "http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="

So now your URL is: "http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://mywebsite/mypdf.pdf"

and open this in your webview. Remember to include this URL in your WebViewClient if you are filtering the urls to open in app or chrome.

Comment: To open url after taping on the link, you need to create a WebView Client which overrides each url like this:

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    //link opener
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".pdf") )
        {
            //create another webview activity and load the url as mentioned above so that it does not keeps on reloading
           myWebView.load(gDrive);
           
        }
        return false;
    }
}

Comment: and set this webview client as:

myWebview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient())

or if you want to load in the same activity/fragment you can modify the condition as:

if(url.endsWith(".pdf") && !url.contains("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="))

and do the same.